# C optimization: Why does the compiler treat an object not as constant?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization

Compiling the following C module

```
static const int i = 1;

void f (const int *i);

int g (void)
{
  f (&i);
  return i;
}
```

using `gcc -S -O3` on an x86_64 maching yields the following assembly for the function `g`:

```
g:
        leaq    i(%rip), %rdi
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    f@PLT
        movl    $1, %eax           # inlined constant as an immediate
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

In other words, the `return` statement is compiled to moving the constant `$1` into the return register `%eax`, which makes sense because `i` is declared constant.

---

However, if I remove that `const` so that I have

```
static int i = 1;

void f (const int *i);

int g (void)
{
  f (&i);
  return i;
}
```

the output of `gcc -S -O3` suddenly becomes:

```
g:
        leaq    i(%rip), %rdi
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    f@PLT
        movl    i(%rip), %eax     # reload i
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

That is, the return value is explicitly loaded from memory after the call to `f`.

Why is this so? The argument to `f` is declared to be a pointer to a constant int, so `f` should not be allowed to alter `i`. Furthermore, `f` cannot call a function that modifies `i` through a non-const reference because the only such function could be `g` as `i` is declared static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not undefined behavior to cast a pointer to const to a pointer to non-const and modify the referenced object, as long as the referenced object is not declared const.

6.7.3p6 says: "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: So does this mean that the compiler has to treat `extern void f(const int *)` and `extern void f(int *)` exactly the same?

Comment: Yes. It makes a difference inside the function, though, because the declaration has to match, and the first function can't write through the pointer without a cast.

Comment: This is only because there is no function body. If the body is unknown compiles has to treat as side effects prone

Comment: @Marc: Yes, they're *exactly* the same as far as ABI / calling convention.  The only difference is compile-time checking that you don't directly modify the pointed-to object through the pointer-to-`const *`.  Fun fact: `foo(const big_object by_value)` still "owns" the stack memory that the object was copied to, in the x86-64 and i386 System V ABIs.  So it can use that stack space as scratch, and the caller has to assume it's clobbered and re-copy it to make another function call with the same object as the argument.  (So the ABI doesn't care about passing a `const` object either.)